# Android app to record notifications

Tags: android, notification, system-monitor

In the process of trying to find a solution to [this Android issue](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/148303/google-play-music-frequently-flashing-in-notification-bar-and-notification-tray), it would be helpful to have an Android app that records every notification posted.

Ideally, it will only record notifications from selected apps, but if it records notifications from all apps, that is fine.

Also, ideally, it will allow copying the text of notifications to the clipboard, but this is *not* a requirement.

I prefer gratis apps, but recommendations for paid apps will be considered.

I prefer that the app not require root, but it's okay if it does.  If it does require root, it's fine if it requires the Xposed framework.

Must be compatible with Android KitKat.

Comment: I have not tried any of them (yet), but you can find some candidates in my list of notification management apps in the section [Backup & History](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_notifications#group_1078).

Comment: Do these have a `toast` accompaniment, maybe?

Comment: @Raystafarian Unfortunately, they do not.

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50177/android-4-3-how-to-get-the-notification-history

Answer (score 1):

I don't know an app specifically for your requirements, but I think you'll find [Notification History](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree&hl=en) useful to see the list of dismissed notifications.

On some phones, there's also a pre-installed widget called **Notification Log** for the exact purpose.